Help with PCB Component Placement
i am currently struggling with this design for my school project.
I would need some help with component placement, because i never get it optimally close together. It is a double sided 4-Layer PCB with the inner layers as GND planes.

The problem here is that i have a seperate GND plane because of the common mode choke after the USB Connector. After this, it leads to the SOP-8 package, load switch mosfets, then to a LC Filter and then to a buck converter (at the bottom side).


I am quite unsure how to place the components, as i do not want the board to get big. I also want to seperate the power stage from the other parts, such as the big MIDI Connector and the Microcontroller.

These are all the components i need to fit onto the pcb. It is definitely possible on this board, but i am not good at placing the components
I am sorry for not posting the Github page, because i dont want it to make it public for reasons.
How would you arrange these things..

If your major components have recommended layouts, that would be a good place to start.


Your buck converter will have a recommended layout and other recommendations in the datasheet. Follow them methodically.

In general placement is difficult for computers so it probably involves more cognitive work. I suggest turning off silk screen layers and other ‘clutter’, just leaving mostly the pads and rat’s nest. Turn off the ground net rat’s nest too since you have ground planes. Remember that you’ll need a bit of room for vias on ground nodes. Adjust trace and via sizes to appropriate values (not too big or small). Probably not an issue in your case but consider changing the schematic to make the layout easier by swapping gates, op-amps in a package. Place critical things like bypass capacitors and connectors and mounting holes early and try not to block off other routing.

Practice. Learning takes time and effort. There are good tutorials, many of them absolutely free. Anything from Robert Ferenac or Phil Salmony is worthwhile.



I personally prefer to leave silkscreen on throughout layout after doing too many redesigns to accommodate component designators.

@vir yes, for not too tight boards that’s an option. Really tight boards tend to drop the designators entirely.

I would recommend moving to a 6 layer design if this is one of your first projects. It would make easier routing and if your time is worth anything the extra 25-50$ would be worth the time you would save routing.
Or you may also want to increase the size of the board if possible

I was going to say that 6 layers is overkill, but I punched in 50x50 mm into JLCPCB and they quoted me the same price for 6 layers as 4 layers, so yeah great suggestion.

It used to be cost prohibitive to do 4 layers, and people would yell at you for wanting to switch. In a lot Asian factories they are runing many panels of 4 and 6 layer designs a day so it's not that expensive to switch.

Hello, thanks for answering my question. The problem here is that my Manufacturer (PCBway) increases the cost a lot from 4 to 6 layers. I think that the biggest problem here is not the large amount of nets (because there are not many), i think that its the amount of components i need to place in such a small space.

Consider the most sensitive parts first. Some rough prioritizing order of placement & routing would be:

Mechanical restraints. Obviously things like connectors, screws and antennas need to be placed as required by the mechanics. The electrical design should adapt to the mechanical design unless there are very specialized requirements (antenna placement etc).
RF/analog parts that are the most sensitive.
High speed (MHz) buses.
Switched voltage regulators.
Other noisy stuff such as oscillators and buzzers.
Fine pitch components. QFP/QFN/BGA usually place in the middle somewhere.
The rest.

There is no good reason to use less than 4 layers, particularly not when you have RF and/or switched voltage regulators and/or fine pitch parts.
Avoid double-sided mounting if possible, since this increases assembly costs. 6 layer single-sided will be cheaper than 2/4 layer double-sided.
If space is tight also consider switching to smaller passives. Ideally stick to one size of passives as standards and only use larger ones where you must (bulk caps etc).
Avoid though-hole components and hand-soldered ones whenever possible, also because of production costs.

Ultimately, the most important thing here was time.
I thought that component placement shouldn't even need a whole day, which was kind of ignorant.
I solved all of my issues now with only 4 Layers and Single-Sided assembly, reducing the overall cost of production.

The layout usually takes about twice the time it takes to do the electric design + schematics. There's a reason why some EE exclusively specialize in doing layouts.
